# How do I become a "follower" for a tag?

Tags: support

I was thinking that becoming a follower will let me know when there are new questions about the tags I'm interested in. However I can't figure out how to become a follower or if becoming one will accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can 'favorite' a tag, there's an item in the sidebar for it:

[image]

Questions with a tag that you have favorited show up in a slightly different color on the home page and question lists, allowing you to find them more easily:

[image]

However, it sounds like what you want is to be able to see new questions in that tag. In that case, just search for [tag] - I.e. [for [gravity]](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgravity%5D). You can combine them by searching for `[tag1] OR [tag2]` - like [this for [gravity] or [planets]](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravity+or+planets). This way you can have a page that you visit to see questions that are in tags you've expressed interest in.

Comment: When you say I can favorite a tag, what screen are you in to do that. Have been trying to duplicate idea. It doesn't seem to be in my profile or in a tag itself. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I spoke too soon, I kept trolling and I found the favorite tags section in my profile and its working just as you said it would! Thanks so much!!